# insert large data into mysql with process bar

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to upload text file to insert into mysql. It works fine with a small number of rows but when rows more than 1000 it's hanging.

My probem is:

1. code is very slow and hanging with large text file
2. process bar not working
3. how it works with text and cvs, xls, xlsx files

The code:

```
//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
$t = "0";

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $num = count($data);
  $mobile=$data[0];
  $mobile = clean_value(mobile_filter($mobile));

  if (preg_match('/^[0-9]{12,12}$/i',$mobile)) { 

    $check_mob = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM book WHERE mobile = '$mobile' AND owner = '$cp_username' AND groupname = '$groupname'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($check_mob) == 0) { 
      $import="INSERT into book(nickname, mobile, groupname, owner) values('$nickname','$mobile','$groupname','$cp_username')";
      mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
      $t = $t+1;
      echo "<div class=\"progress\">
              <div class=\"progress-bar\" role=\"progressbar\" aria-valuenow=\"$t\" aria-valuemin=\"0\" aria-valuemax=\"100\" style=\"width:$t%\">
                $t%
              </div>
            </div>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use Jquery and set intervals to upload. if you do not have fast server it can just overload the process and will stop responding. Try timer and make code save e.g 500 rows then wait for few seconds then save another 500 and so on..

Comment: give me 2 min i will write you  a demo

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do this with using only PHP too.

This is a example code.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO .....";

$count++;

if($count==500){
// wait for 5 seconds
usleep(5000000);
 $count=0;
}
```

You will need to put this code in the loop that you save line by line into database. When the system saves first 500 record, it will sleep for 5 seconds and continue.

Comment: reduce the row count to 200 or try jQuery

Comment: i traid count 100 in firset time

Comment: how big is the file you are uploading?

Comment: i traid file 500 rows 7 kilobyte only